# Query by key in Datastore with Dart

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `List<Key>` which I would like to retrieve the full data records for but with applying additional filtering to it.

I can retrieve them via `dbService.lookup(Project, keys)` but `lookup` doesn't allow me to apply additional filtering.

This is essentially what I want to do:

```
dbService.query(Project)
  ..filter('__key__ IN', keys)
  ..filter('acl_read IN', roles)
  ..run();
```

but since `__key__` is not supported in Google Cloud's Dart implementation, I cannot run this query.

I could do:

```
projects = dbService.lookup(keys);
projects.removeWhere((project) => (project.acl_read.fold(false, (result, key) => result || members.contains(key))));
```

but this seems not like the right way of achieving this.

So what's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a server-based method to do what you're looking to do, so your method of post filtering on the client-side is how you'd do it..

Alternatively, if you know that all querying all the keys with your filter results in a small set of keys then what you have in List, then do a full query first and then find the Union of results and List

Comment: I do not understand your alternative solution. Do you mean: `query('acl_read IN', roles).keys UNION keys`? Would this be faster?